# Is there an Extension for Microsoft VS Code to lint `.java` files and compile to `.class`?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I've literally looked for many extensions that support Java but in vain. I want an extension that can create .class file from .java on the go upon saving the files.
Extensions I've already tried :

1. Java Extension Pack (by Microsoft)
2. Java Linter (by Faustino Aguilar)

None of them worked according to my needs even though all extensions have access to `JAVA_HOME` environment variable created already during JDK installation!

Comment: Looking at Java Extension Pack's feature list, I think it expects you to use Maven as a build tool. But to be brutally honest, there are several open source and extremely good Java IDEs out there, why not just use them?

Comment: Yes, obviously I can and I am using Atom for Java, since it has an extension that automatically compiles java files. But I just love VS Code, so needed an extension in this itself

Comment: I'm not talking about Atom, more about classic things like Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans, et cetera. Things that are built from the ground up for Java.

Comment: I don't want much complex support for Java. I just want one thing .....LOL